# How do I use multi-touch gestures on a MacBook Air?

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, macbook, multi-touch

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on my MacBook Air (13" mid 2011) and it works lovely! Are there any news or possibilites to use multi-touch gestures?

But to now I am using the system out of the box. One and two finger gestures are working.

Comment: Have you tried [Touchégg](http://code.google.com/p/touchegg/)?

Comment: Thanks. Touchégg looks quite interesting. I installed it but it crashed when I started it in the terminal: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/touchegg/+bug/955380

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu supports a range of multi touch moves out of the box. Although ive noticed that some

of the don't work in unity2d, so i recomend staying with unity.

Touching the pad with four fingers : will pop up the search field
sliding over a window with three fingers:  move that window
spread three fingers over a window : maximize window
the opposite will minimize the window.

Comment: Funny. On my Macbook Air (mid 2011) there is no difference between the touch moves in unity and unity2d. I only have the 2 finger moves. But thank you anyway.

Comment: Now I is also working fine on my Macbook Air. The last updates erased the bugs...

Comment: i havent tried unity2d for a while. But unity 3d has a couple of moves like:

* 4 finger press (brings up the search)
* 3 finger spread (maximises window)
* 3 finger move (moves current window)
* 4 finger swipe (hides / shows  launcher)